# Get all types in an interface

Tags: typescript

I was just wondering whether it is possible to extract all of the types in an interface and have a new type as union of them all.

For example, given something like this:

```
interface T {
  a: TypeA;
  b: TypeB;
  c: TypeC;
}
```

and result in

```
type U = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to get the union of all the types in an interface:

```
type ValuesOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type U = ValuesOf<T>;
```

[image]